# How to prevent GNU indent from breaking initialization assignment like "= { 0 };"

Tags: c, indentation, indent

See following example.

```
$ indent --version
GNU indent 2.2.10
$ cat foo.c
void foo()
{
    struct {
        int a;
        int b;
    } v = { 0 };
}
$ indent -st foo.c
void
foo ()
{
  struct
  {
    int a;
    int b;
  } v =
  {
  0};
}
$
```

I don't want `= { 0 };` to be formatted to

```
=
{
0};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also the case with 2.2.11. From looking into the code, it seems to be a bug with block initializers not being properly detected. In this case, indent forces a newline after the '{'. I've been hacking around on it over the last couple of days and fixed this bug in [my working copy](https://github.com/thentenaar/indent) such that your file would be formatted like so:

```
$ src/indent -npro -st foo.c
void
foo ()
{
  struct
  {
    int a;
    int b;
  } v = { 0 };
}
```

Feel free to checkout my working copy and give it a try. Otherwise you'll likely have to wait until it's fixed upstream.